# Preserve Font Size when scaling a Drawing

Tags: .net, gdi+

I do the following when drawing:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix()
m.Scale(_zoomX, _zoomY)

e.Graphics.Transform = m

e.Graphics.DrawLine(...) ' line representation '
e.Graphics.DrawString(...) ' line text '
```

Now, the text became also scaled. Is it possible to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change only the point coordonates, use instead of:

```
e.Graphics.Transform = m
```

this one:

```
m.TransformPoints(points)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Try to adjust the font to size/_zoom when drawing it

Answer (score 1):

Matrix work with image and do not distinguishes if it text or shape.
If text position is not relevant, you can reset e.Graphics.Transform

```
 Matrix oldMAtrix = e.Graphics.Transform;
 e.Graphics.Transform = m;
 e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 20, 20, 20);
 e.Graphics.Transform = oldMAtrix;
 e.Graphics.DrawString("text", this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, 10, 10);
```

Comment: I shoudl use `e.Graphics.ResetTransform()` then `p = New PointF(_ZoomX * oldp.X, oldp.Y * _ZoomY)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to undo the Graphics transform and draw your text with an Identity (or at least non scaling) transform.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do the math yourself to transform the text insertion position into the scaled matrix. But you cannot draw the text with a scaling matrix active.